# Is there a standard for naming stocks exchanges?  Is there a list of abbreviated names?

Tags: stock-exchanges, quotes

If I want to refer to a stock that is traded at a specific exchange how do I specify the name of the exchange?

And is there a list of all the shortcuts for the names of all the exchanges in the world?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wikipedia is your friend:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_stock_exchanges

Comment: thanks, this is a good list and answers the second part of my Q.

Comment: but how do I refer to a stock in those exchanges?
NASDAQ:AAPL ?  AAPL.NASDAQ ?

Comment: @epeleg: I understand what you mean either way.  What are you trying to do?  I've seen the first one more often than the second.

Comment: I wam writing some software that handles stocks and wanted to know which of the two is more common or is there a standard mapping between them.

Comment: Maybe start here:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ticker_symbol

Comment: thanks for another good link. seems like generally speaking its a mess... :) but I think I will go with something like exch:ticker.